# In technology, what options does a jack of all trades have?

Tags: career-development, team-role

Subject:
A jack of all trades (and master of none), in a technology company (for this question) would be somebody who is familiar with most relevant technologies and keeps up to date with them without being the best expert around.

Question: in a technology company (IT, software, biotech), what are the career paths for a "jack of all trades"?
I am talking about traditional job roles where this background is a competitive advantage.

Another way of phrasing it is: are there career paths where being a jack of all trades is desirable?

Comment: Career paths are specialisation if you want to rise, jack of all trades tend to end up with the grunt work in a tech company. In a smaller non tech company they're great assets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Many rewarding paths.**

Still, hard paths requiring creativity and ability to sell yourself, not just the working-harder-than-the-guy-next-desk-and-get-promotion kind of path. And yes in the long run, the more you find your niche the more likely you`ll look like the already mentioned T-shape employee, nothing bad about that tho.

**Entrepreneur**: *This was my first job* (somehow, I started off with a startup and with some luck there was a good idea behind it) your skillset must include (or probably have its focus on...) business stuff, but being able to envision a solution to a problem, put together a team able to make it real and sell it to companies in need is a satisfactions like few others.

**Consultant**: The company calls you with a problem, you understand the problem in its various ramification and elaborate a solution. The company provides you the resource you asked to solve the problem and you fix it. *This was my previous job*, requires mainly ability to persuade, to compromise and to be realistic and not idealistic in regards to technology.

**System Integrator**: mainly in a company, *this is what I do now*. You are the one that decides how the new production machine is going to communicate with the old-proprietary database your company is using and also builds the proposed solution. You`ll also be asked to envision a way to improve quality control but from times to times you'll change the office printer cartridge or fix the kettle.

**Technologist**: TBH, I know only one. A former college professor that seems to see the future of semiconductors, is paid around a million a year to travel the world at his will and tell them what the next hot thing is going to be. A job for very experienced and absolutely our of the ordinary people. *Maybe one day....*

Answer (score 8):

Grow expertise in one area and become a T-shaped person.

You can read about it in the Valve Software's HANDBOOK FOR
NEW EMPLOYEES available [here](http://www.valvesoftware.com/company/Valve_Handbook_LowRes.pdf).

Here's a picture from this handbook:
[image: Valve's T-Shaped person]

You can also check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-shaped_skills

Comment: Thanks for linking that handbook, I didn't know that even existed. It's a really interesting read, and as a software developer I found it fascinating. Nice one.

Answer (score 2):

> are there career paths where being a jack of all trades is desirable?

Most definitely! There are lots of career paths where someone can climb the corporate ladder by being a "generalist". One I can think of is HR. However, in a tech environment, there is also a career path. This known as being a "[full-stack](http://codeup.com/what-is-a-full-stack-developer/)" developer. This means you know a little bit of everything. Full stack developers have an opportunity to be on the business side because they often times have to understand the business needs for an application - not the just technical.

Answer (score -5):

I would be extremely skeptical of someone who claimed to be a "Jack of all trades" in technology. There are very few people who are even qualified full-stack developers. Are you saying you know a little bit of every computer language I can name? Are you a competent front-end developer? How's your SQL? What about Dev Ops? Can you write a good bash script and spin up some Docker containers with it so we can have a simplified development environment setup for the rest of the team? How's your crypography and ML? Of course all trades would include hardware I suppose, how are your soldiering skills?

Also, if you're not good at any of those things, then why should I hire you? A mediocre developer might introduce more bugs than they fix. They might create a security nightmare for me.

A "jack of all trades/master of none" probably doesn't know much about the field to begin with. They probably don't even know the entire breath of it. I would assume that someone who describes themselves that way would be very niaeve.